# Middleman 3.0 - simple-navigation gem

Tags: ruby, navigation, padrino, middleman

Would anyone with Ruby knowledge know if its possible to use the Padrino compatible version of the '[simple-navigation](https://github.com/andi/sinatra-simple-navigation)' gem with Middleman 3.0?

I would like to implement multilevel navigation + breadcrumbs and have a bit of control over the ordering.

Or is there any other navigation gems or examples anyone could point me in the direction of that works with Middleman 3.0?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a gem that wraps this up for you:

[middleman-navigation](https://github.com/michaek/middleman-navigation)

Comment: This gem looks great, but it doesn't appear to be compatible with Middleman 3.1.x. See https://github.com/michaek/middleman-navigation/issues/8#issuecomment-25368264